# How can I print the weights of a Keras weight.h5 file?

Tags: keras, h5py

I have an h5 file produced by Keras, I would like to print the weight values in Python. Thanks

Comment: Have you written any code? You can open the file in Python with `h5py` or `tables` (PyTables) modules. From there, access the weights data set and print as you normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did (for my own problem)

```
import h5py
keys = []
with h5py.File("The-subnet-weight.h5",'r') as f: # open file
    f.visit(keys.append) # append all keys to list
    for key in keys:
            if ':' in key: # contains data if ':' in key
                print(f[key].name)

import numpy as np  #Define the info to extract
f = h5py.File("The-subnet-weight.h5",'r')
group = f[key]
b4 = group['/dense_5/dense_5/bias:0'].value
k4= group['/dense_5/dense_5/kernel:0'].value
K4=np.transpose(np.array(k4)) #Process
   
f.close() #Close key

from numpy import savetxt #Save as human readable
savetxt('b4.csv', b4, delimiter=',')
savetxt('w4.csv', K4, delimiter=',')
```